# how can use create command query maker

Tags: php, yii, cdb

I have a query like this

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `tbl_one` t1 LEFT JOIN `tbl_two` t2 on       t1.idea_id = t2.id WHERE create_time >=:t")->bindValues(array(":t" =>$start))->queryScalar();
```

in yii farme work but dosent work!!
please help me

Answer (score 1):

you can remove `queryScalar()`, since it will try to get one result from database,

and use `queryAll()` to get all results

Answer (score 0):

It is not the answer, because tinybyte already answed it. for yii better understanding. please see

```
 // execute a query SQL
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($yoursql)->query(); 

 // query and return all rows of result        
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($yoursql)->queryAll();  

  // query and return the first row of result     
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($yoursql)->queryRow(); 

 // query and return the first column of result
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($yoursql)->queryColumn();  

 // query and return the first column of result
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($yoursql)->queryScalar();
```